# Can't archive app in Xcode5: validation error

Tags: xcode

previously i can archive using Xcode4, but when i use Xcode 5, it says:

```
Validate /Users/decky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MegaInsurence-gpczifaskugghlbbvtppfctksyih/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MegaInsurence/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MegaInsurence.app
    cd "/Users/decky/Documents/ios-project/Mega Insurence"
    setenv PATH "/Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/decky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MegaInsurence-gpczifaskugghlbbvtppfctksyih/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MegaInsurence/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MegaInsurence.app

2014-01-09 12:34:53.587 Validation[6561:f07] Could not load framework at “file://localhost/Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application%20Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/” (err = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “ITunesSoftwareService” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources." (dlopen_preflight(/Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService): Library not loaded: @rpath/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ITunesConnectFoundation
  Referenced from: /Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService
  Reason: image not found) UserInfo=0x7fcb3ae148b0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService): Library not loaded: @rpath/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ITunesConnectFoundation
  Referenced from: /Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService
  Reason: image not found, NSBundlePath=/Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “ITunesSoftwareService” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.})
error: Application validati
```

can someone tell whats wrong?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your Xcode installation, did you try downloading Xcode via the App Store or did you download it from somewhere else?

Comment: It seems so, i redownload xcode and reinstall it and now it is fixed thanks